# Widget no Shiny para pegar um caminho de arquivo

Tags: r, shiny

Em uma aplicação aqui do trabalho eu utilizo o widget abaixo para que o usuário carregue uma base de dados e ela seja 'criticada'por um outro script.

```
 fileInput("file1", "Escolha o arquivo",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv",".xlsx"))
```

Em outra aplicação eu preciso que o usuário forneça o caminho aonde estão os arquivos a serem analisados. Sei que posso alterar o parâmetro `multiple = TRUE` e funcionará parecido com o que eu quero, mas gostaria de widget que pediria o caminho dos arquivos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) de fato não tem uma função para isso. Para contornar essa "restrição" do `shiny` foi criado o pacote [`shinyFiles`](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles).

Esse pacote tem duas funções para auxiliar nessa missão:

1. `shinyDirButton`: vai na UI e cria o botão;
2. `shinyDirChoose`: vai no server e "pega" o input passado pelo usuário.

Uma aplicação que use o módulo fica assim:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

dir.create("teste")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  p("Escolha uma pasta"),
  shinyDirButton("pasta", "Escolher", "Escolha uma pasta"),
  hr(),
  verbatimTextOutput("dir")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # chama o módulo
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'pasta', roots=c(wd='.'))

  # torna resposta reativa
  pasta <- reactive(input$pasta)

  # joga resposta no output
  output$dir <- renderPrint( pasta() )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Tela inicial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Modal após apertar o botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado após escolher a pasta "teste":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que para usar o valor passado pelo usuário você terá de manipular `pasta()$path`. Geralmente seu primeiro elemento é desprezível (`""`) e portanto o valor passado de fato é `pasta()$path[-1]`.

Comment: Era isso que eu estava procurando, irei adaptar para a minha aplicação, muito obrigado!